# Difference between jQuery Production and jQuery Development?

Tags: jquery

This question might sound stupid but pls be patient because I am a total beginner. I downloaded both jQuery versions, development and production. I want to know what is better for me to use as a beginner for studying jQuery.

Comment: Your question isn't stupid at all. +1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are interested in the inner workings of jQuery, use the development version. Its source code is formatted nicely and documented/commented for a developer to refer to.

If you only want to learn how to **use** jQuery, refer to the [manual](http://api.jquery.com) instead.

The production version is a [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) version of the same source file. This reduces the number of bytes taken up by the file, thereby saving bandwidth for production use in web apps as it gets served to a browser for use.

Comment: +1. Worth noting: debugging can also be easier with the development version, since your error messages won't include cryptic, minified/replaced variable names.

Comment: Thanks bro... I think I'll go for the development version for studying.

Comment: I mean development... I edited my comment... I just got confused between the two...

Answer (score 6):

jQuery Production is compressed, jQuery Development is not.
If you are learning jQuery, both library is the same unless you want to see the jQuery core code.

If you want to use it on your website, then you should use the Production version.

Answer (score 5):

The production version is meant to be used in a working application. The development is by a developer while developing said application.

The development version is minimised. That means all extraneous whitespaces, including newlines, are removed. In contrast, the development version is just like how one normally writes a code. Variable names are more likely to be in full and each statements rests on its own line. This makes it much easier to debug as you can now put breakpoints on jQuery's code and inspect the variables.

To aid you in doing that (debug, that is), I recommend developing using Firefox with the Firebug plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The production version is a minified version of the same source file. The development is by a developer while developing said application.